# A problem regarding only

Tags: adverbs

In the following sentence

> The CEO only discussed the new venture with
>   his manager.

According to the answer keys provided the above sentence is wrong. They say **only** should be used before **the CEO**  . But I think it is grammatical. The use of only is correct in the above sentence.

Comment: Was this sentence presented in any context, or just an isolated sentence?

Comment: It is just an isolated sentence

Comment: This use of "his manager" is weird.  Usually, someone's manager is the boss of that person.  But CEOs are the highest ranking executives in companies.  A CEO reports to a Board of Directors, not a single "boss".

Comment: A male shop owner might appoint a person to be the manager and run the store. That person would be his (the owner's) manager. It's a term of ownership, like *his employee*, but specifically *his employee that is a manager*. But that's very long winded. Seems completely natural to me. Especially as you point out, as a CEO there can be no ambiguity here as to whether it's his boss/line-manager or his subordinate-who-is-also-a-manager

Comment: What answer keys? This question is not acceptable. No context, no explanation, no nothing. Of course, the word only cannot precede CEO here.

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you mean

> The CEO only discussed the new venture with his manager.

This would normally mean the CEO did not discuss the new venture with anyone else. (The manager could well have talked to others about it, or had no other conversations at all)
A second more obscure meaning could be that it was only a discussion, rather than an actual solid plan to put into practice (ie it was just a hypothetical discussion, no actions)

> Only the CEO discussed the new venture with his manager.

This would mean that nobody except the CEO discussed the new venture with the manager (*So the CEO may have told others*) The manager did not have a discussion with anyone else.

Answer (score 0):

The use of only is correct.

Saying "The only CEO discussed..." would mean "There were several people who discussed various topics, but only one of the people was a CEO, and that person discussed the new venture." That would be a very odd meaning.  As written it means that the CEO discussed the new venture and nothing else, or possibly it means the CEO discussed the new venture with his manager and nobody else (it is ambiguous).

The error here is one of semantics (ie meaning) The abbrievation "CEO" means "Chief Executive Officer". The CEO is the most senior person working at a company. A CEO does not have a manager, so it would be impossible for a CEO to discuss something with his manager.

Comment: But the CEO may appoint managers to assist him and then discuss the subject with his managers

Comment: Won't that be correct?

Comment: The are not "his manager".  His manager means the person who manages him.

Comment: Quoting the question, it is about the assertion that "**only** should be used before **the CEO**". In other words: "Only the CEO discussed". Your phrase, "The only CEO discussed" isn't part of this question.